# How to show drop down(CommandBarComboBox) control in VBA Word Add-In in Mac OS?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have created a template Add-In (dotm template in Word's startup folder).

Let me clear that how I have created it.

`Open Ms Word in Windows OS--> Pressed Alt + F11 --> Add one Module and put function of create buttons there ---> Saved file as .dotm---> put this .dotm file in Word folder of AppData folder in both Widnows and Mac OS.`

It is one kind of Macro. It is working fine just one issue of Drop Down controls. I have created it(Add-In/Macro) which has 3 drop down control(CommandBarComboBox) for filter and 1 Button with drop down option(CommandBarControl)

In Windows OS Office, when I add this add-In, it shows a new tab name "Add-In" and show my controls in it. It perfect as I require.

But in Mac OS Office, it doesn't show 3 drop down control(CommandBarComboBox) for filter. It just show 1 Button with drop down(CommandBarControl) as new Tab.

Can anybody suggest how can I show dropdown(CommandBarComboBox)?
Also suggest me what does this development call? Add-Ins or Macro or anything else?
[image]

Comment: You need to be specific about what you mean by "add-in". There are at least four different types supported by Word-for-Windows; most of them are not supported by Mac.

Comment: @CindyMeister I don't know what it is called. Open word--> Press ALT + F11 --> Add function and save file as .dotm. It is one kind of Macro. Put this .dotm file in Word folder of AppData in both Window and Mac OS. You will see it is working perfectly without any error in Windows and Mac OS. Can you please tell me what should I call this development technology?? Tell me name of it so, I keep in my mind before asking again else I will use "Add-In" again as I don't know what does it call. I hope you got my point.

Comment: "Template add-in" is the correct term - a .dotm template in the Word applications Startup folder :-) And this question is going to need to be answered by a Mac person, although I suspect it could be because the version of the Mac you're on doesn't support customized Ribbon XML. But I don't work on Mac, so I'm not sure...